Build images in different jobs (amd64 & arm64) and push them together
I want to build images in different jobs. To build the arm64 one in a self hosted runner, how can I push them together, so they won't overwrite?
name: Docker build and publish

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build_amd64:
    name: Build amd64
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3.3.0

      - name: Build Docker image
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          platforms: linux/amd64
          push: false
          tags: ghcr.io/montejojorge/electrs-ui:latest

  build_arm64:
    name: Build arm64
    runs-on: [self-hosted, linux, ARM64]
    steps:
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3.3.0

      - name: Build Docker image
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          platforms: linux/arm64
          push: false
          tags: ghcr.io/montejojorge/electrs-ui:latest

If I login to a registry and set push: true, the one that finishes first will be overwritten by the last.

Did you check this section on the doc?

@GuiFalourd Yes, but i want to build it in separate jobs, so i can run the arm64 in a arm64 selfhosted runner and the amd64 in the github runner

Did you try using a matrix strategy like suggested there? With 2 fields: platform (with linux/arm64 and linux/amd64) and os (with ubuntu-latest and your self-hosted runner)

With that way, 4 jobs will run, and each job will push a new image

You're right, my bad. To have 2 jobs you would need to create a JSON list object in the matrix strategy. Something like this: configs: [{"platform":"linux/arm64", "os": "self-hosted" }, {"platform":"linux/amd64", "os": "ubuntu-latest" }], and access the values in the matrix job by using ${{ matrix.configs.platform }} or ${{ matrix.configs.os }}.

Have you considered multi-platform images?

@BenjaminW. Yes, i can build it in the same job, but i want to use my self hosted runner, just for he arm one, so it will be much faster (x5 times)

@GuiFalourd same problem, one job will overwrite the image

It may be a limitation on this docker/build-push-action action. The doc states that deploying using platforms: linux/arm64, linux/amd64 should work using the same image tag, but if doing it separately overwrite the first push tag, something doesn't seem to be working as expected
